# Suspicious spatial join with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I have a shapefile with a large number of lakes from which I'm trying to select the ones that are the closest to a set of regularly spaced points. To do so, I created a fishnet and then created a spatial join between my lake shapefile and the fishnet. I made sure that both the lake and the fishnet have the same projection.
I created the spatial join as follows:

[image]

In the environment tab, I specified that the output coordinate system and the extent should be the same as the inputs. The output appears to me nonsensical.

[image]

First, I didn't get the field distance_from_fishnet field I was supposed to get, the field is missing. Second, it seems that lake records are paired to themselves as the record FID is always the same as OBJECTID and TARGET_FID. Third, I've 4911 records in my fishnet, but 119000+ lake records where Join_Count = 1 while I asked for the closest item (I guess I should get max 4911 records with Join_Count = 1). Finaly, the visual inspection doesn't make much sense either... Selected features on the picture below are the ones closest to the fishnet (dark dots).

[image]

I start doubting that I even understood the principle of a spatial join.

Edit: By rerunning exactly the same procedure as second time, I got the distance_from_fishnet field, but still nonsensical values.

Comment: Try other way around - spatial join points to lake, thus for 12 points you'll have 12 lakes.

Comment: This doesn't work with the tool "Add Spatial Join". However, I just figured out that "Spatial Join" (Analysis tools) and "Add Spatial Join" (Data management) give quite different results! By using Spatial Join with the "join to many", and as you said, the points as target and lake as join feature, it is possible to find the point/lake matching ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the tool "Add Spatial Join" from the Data management toolbox is working the way it was meant to (currently using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2). While certain fields like "Distance field name" were accurately displaying the distance between the target and the join feature, the target ID was always pointing to the same value join ID (I could switch the target and join features and got similar results). It behaved like I was joining the tables by ID

So instead of using "Add Spatial Join", I used "Spatial Join" from Analysis toolbox. It creates a new feature that can be in turn joined to the original target feature based on ID.